# encoding trouble while sending info on server

Tags: java, character-encoding

I try to send info to server. charset encoding set to UTF-8. jsp page encoding also set to **UTF-8**. I use Spring mvc

I form json and try to send it to server. but when when I get response body I see strange symbols between words `attributeCategory%5B0%5D%5Batt`.
I searched and all suggestions were to have encoding utf-8 to resolve such problem.

**UPDATE**

When I add on server side this line `URLDecoder.decode(body, "ISO-8859-1");` everything was encoded in normal form. So my question what I need to change with my json or something else to make my program work with UTF-8 encoding

Comment: If the Content-Type header of your response is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you should run your response body text through [`URLDecoder.decode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).  And as the documentation recommends, you should pass "UTF-8" as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

- `%5B` = `[` (hexadecimal code 5B)
- `%5D` = `]` (hexadecimal code 5D)

This might stem from HTML INPUT fields with the same name, so in fact `attributeCategory[0][att` was meant (probably miscopied here).

It could also be JavaScript.

It is a url encoding for HTTP transmission of non-basic characters like `[`, `]` and so on. Nothing to do with an encoding.

I hope this points to some cause of this error.

Comment: so I need add something to my ajax code or write something like charset filter at server side to get normal text with [] symbols instead of %5B???

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea. Why should something like `attributeCategory[0]` be transmitted? If as JSON field name `{ name : "value" }`, place the entire string in quotes too (`"name"`).